# Get list of all used sources

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Our team was assigned to review and refractor some big and complex product. Current repo has a lot of unused files. We need to figure out which files are used and which are not.

Is there an easy way to get all sources and headers files that are used by a build system (make) to compile the product?

Comment: `find . -name "*.c"`

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant How about the unused files in the repository? It looks like Kentzo wants to find `*.c` that should *not* be there.

Comment: @harper Excactly. Sources actually are easy (as you noted in your answer). I need the solution for headers.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer sources the .C and .CPP files you should verify that your build system generates map files. You can parse the map files with regular expression to find all .o files. This gives you the name of all source files.

Header files can be found with a grep for #include lines.

Edit:

The GCC can output the dependencies with the `-M` or `-MM` option. You could parse these files. If your makefile calls GCC you could change the CFLAGS to create those files. If other compilers provide this features is compiler dependent.

Comment: Unfortunately the codebase is just a blood mess. Grepping files will be pain in the ass because of duplicates and sophisticated makefiles. If possible I would like to get that information directly from the compiler after everything is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dependency generating parameters to compiler. G++ has set of -M* options, which allow you to generate dependencies of each file in Makefile format. I didn't use it much, so I won't tell you exactly what you should do, but perhaps `-MP` may look promising for your problem...

Just save those dependency files with some fancy extension like .ddd, and then write a script to accumulate them somewhere.